# How to configure Webpack-simple with Vue Cli 3?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

Just to make it easier, I'm new to Vue Cli and Vue as whole.

In Vue Cli 2, I think it was something like this:

```
Vue init webpack-simple xxx
```

But now in the newest major update (3) it is like this:

```
Vue create xxx
```

And it can't you give an option to install Webpack-simple

I tried to do this 
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration 
but I'm not sure that it's what I want. Is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install `@vue/cli-init` for `init` to work with vue cli 3.

[Vue docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#pulling-2-x-templates-legacy):

> Vue CLI 3 uses the same vue binary, so it overwrites Vue CLI 2 (vue-cli). If you still need the legacy vue init functionality, you can install a global bridge:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli-init
# vue init now works exactly the same as vue-cli@2.x
vue init webpack my-project
```

Comment: Can't I do it without doing that? I want some of Vue Cli 3 features though.

Comment: Not with webpack-simple. The standard way is to use `vue create` now, which creates its own configuration. Do have any questions regarding the new method?

Comment: i meant is there any way to set up Webpack within the project without installing "Cli init"?

Comment: Not in the same way. Vue cli 3 uses `cli-service` which is built on top of webpack. You can modify its configuration with plugins and your own configuration files. Have you gone through the `vue create` steps?

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: What is your next step? Are you trying to prototype, build, add a pre-processor/rule or modify configuration?

Comment: All that I want is just creating a project.

Comment: `vue create <project-name>` will do just that. You can view it by running `npm run serve` in the <project-name> directory.

Comment: But how I include Webpack in it? Is the above way the only way to do it?

Comment: You can modify the internal webpack configuration by merging a vue.config.js file, installing plugins, or providing additional options. Can you explain what exactly you want to configure in webpack? A Vue CLI 3 project can be run and developed without these.

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for answering.